# Total differential -- which point do I use?

Tags: calculus

I'm working through Mary L. Boas's Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences and have come across either a confusion or an error in the text. (p. 197, 3rd edition.)

I am asked to show that when n is very large $\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} = \frac{2}{n^3}$.  (This equality should be approximate; I just don't know how to write that.)  The author takes $df = d \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{-2dn}{n^3}$.  But then she takes $dn = -1$.

It seems to me that, in order for us to use $dn = -1$, we must use $d \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$.  (Of course, using this does not result in the required result.)  In fact, the author does this very thing in the previous exercise.

Where am I going wrong here?  Or am I right, and this is a mistake in the text?

Comment: `\approx` produces $\approx$.

Comment: Actually, $f(n)=1/n^2$ so $\Delta f = f(n+1)-f(n) = 1/(n+1)^2-n^2 \approx f'(n) (n+1-n) = f'(n) < 0$. What you have up there is not $f(n+1)-f(n)$ but the opposite.

Comment: In terms of approximations, $\frac{2}{(n+1)^3} = \frac{2}{n^3}$. Might have been better to say $dn = 1$ and then multiply with $-1$, since the expression is $f(n) - f(n+1)$ and not $f(n+1)-f(n)$.

Comment: That's just what I was saying.  The author, apparently, disagrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^{-2}$. By the mean value theorem, we can write $$f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\xi)$$ for some $x<\xi<x+1$. As $x\to\infty$, $\xi\to\infty$. What is $f'(\xi)$? Does it go to zero as $\xi\to\infty$? It seems the author is writing $$x^{-2}-(1+x)^{-2}=f(x)-f(x+1)=-f'(\xi)={2}\xi^{-3}$$ since $x-(x+1)=-1$. That is the "$dn=-1$" she is suggesting. Morover, since $x<\xi<x+1$ we have $\dfrac{\xi}x\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$, so $2\xi^{-3}\sim 2x^{-3}$ as $x\to\infty$; as claimed.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why the derivative of f(x) was taken, rather than that of f(x+1).  Also, I don't understand the first half of your comment.  That isn't what the mean value theorem says... aren't you off by a factor?  I didn't downvote you, by the way.

Comment: @JamesDolinger I had a typo. Now fixed.

Comment: Maybe I didn't state my question well enough: I agree with all of this and understand it.  But that doesn't change that what the author did is wrong, as written.  In order to do this problem correctly, it seems you must multiply by -1 at the start and finish of it.  This was not stated, and the differential of the wrong function was taken.  Do you agree that, as written, the author made a mistake?

Comment: If we just multiply at the beginning and end, we can take dn = 1, using the differential of 1/n^2; this, I think, is the correct way.

Comment: @JamesDolinger No, the author is not wrong. As I explain, since you're looking at $f(x)-f(x+1)$ what you have is a decrease, not in increment, for $x-(x+1)=-1$. Thus, the author is correct that "$dn=-1$".

Comment: But the differential should be taken of f(x+1), in that case, should it not?  If we're decrementing from f(x+1), we must take the derivative of 1/(n+1)^2.  This is clearly not the same as the derivative of 1/n^2, and we don't reach the required answer.

Comment: @JamesDolinger No. The mean value theorem writes $$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(\xi)$$ 

In this case we're simply taking $y=x+1$. There is no problem with that.

Comment: I see that you are right, though I maintain that the way the author has written it in the book (maybe you would agree if you saw it) is confusing at best.  Thank you very much.